# MySQL Construct to return sorted counted list

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have a table TABLE with four columns, COL 1..4

```
COL1   COL2   COL3   COL4
Truck  Toyota Pickup 5000
Car    Lexus  Sedan  3000
Car    Lexus  Sedan  6000
Truck  Toyota Pickup 2000
Car    Lexus  Sedan  2000
```

I need to be able to return from a query all Unique COL1's (Trucks, Cars in this case) along with the total sum of occurrences ordered from highest total count first and perhaps some other fields (such as COL2)  although no work needs to be done on these as the uniqueness is only based on one column so in this case would be returned:

```
Car   Lexus  3
Truck Toyota 2
```

This my seem trivial but I am not sure how to perform the query (MySQL) *and* in the most efficient way (will be done hundreds of times a second potentially).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Arth gave correct answer and most likely it's best performed query possible. But if you really will call this hundreds of times per second, then maybe you have to overthink this approach and actually create some statistics table with these count or somehow cache resultset at least for some seconds. Otherwise your DB will have quite heavy load even if query_cache and all other settings will be tuned up.

Comment: Many thanks. I will heed your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple:

```
  SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) count
    FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2 /* I like to include all non-aggregate cols for sanity */
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Oh and you'll want an index on `col1` at the least.

A covering index on all the non-aggregate columns `(col1,col2)` may increase performance further as the query can be satisfied from the index.